# Getting issue while iterating XML file using Elementtree

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have the following XML file. I am using python 3.6 I need to pass the environment name and read the xml into a dictionary and final output in excel file, I have tried using ElementTree, but unsure how to build dict containing. Any suggestions, please..
sample xml file.

```
<response code="19" status="success"><result count="1" total-count="1">
  <nat>
    <rules>
      <entry name="no-nat-1">
        <to>
          <member>Internet</member>
        </to>
        <from>
          <member>Corp</member>
          <member>DMZ</member>
        </from>
        <source>
          <member>CORP-DC-IPZ</member>
          <member>corp-hub-ipz-10.223.0.0-16</member>
          <member>CORP-OFFICE-DO-NOT-USE</member>
        </source>
        <destination>
          <member>CORP-RS</member>
        </destination>
        <service>any</service>
        <nat-type>ipv4</nat-type>
        <target>
          <negate>no</negate>
        </target>
        <description>CRQ00000001 ab;CRQ00000001 ab;CRQ0000000q ab; </description>
        <tag>
          <member>network</member>
        </tag>
      </entry>
      <entry name="NO-NAT-BR2-1">
        <to>
          <member>Corp</member>
        </to>
        <from>
          <member>Internet</member>
        </from>
        <source>
          <member>CORP-ROUTERS</member>
        </source>
        <destination>
          <member>CORP-DC-IPZ</member>
          <member>CORP-OFFICE-IPZ-DO-NOT-USE</member>
          <member>corp-hub-ipz-10.223.0.0-16</member>
        </destination>
        <service>any</service>
        <nat-type>ipv4</nat-type>
        <target>
          <negate>no</negate>
        </target>
        <description>CRQ00000001 ab;CRQ00000001 ab;</description>
      </entry>
      /rules>
  </nat>
</result></response>
```

I have tried to retrieve  XML data using JSON and element tree

```
import xmltodict
import pprint
import json

with open('nat.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read(),process_namespaces=True)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(json.dumps(doc))
```

I want to iterate XML file and store output as excel

Comment: Does the `xmltodict` work? How should the Excel file look like?  I am asking since your xml is not flat and excel is flat.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for reaching me. The excel should be like that. I am trying to use XML to dict library.